# Elasticsearch and keeping relational data consistent

Tags: php, elasticsearch, foreign-keys, consistency

Currently working out a concept where we will be implementing a module that will take care of the synchronisation of data to an Elasticsearch index.

In the current platform (that is backed by a MySQL database), most of the data is stored with foreign keys and, as far as I know, Elasticsearch stores the data in the exact opposite way: flat without any relations...

Let's assume we have the following entities:

- person
- organisation
- address

In the MySQL db, both a person and an organisation have a foreign key to address.

When syncing a person/organisation to Elasticsearch, we would like to include all address info for that particular entity. On top of that we would also like to store individual addresses in Elasticsearch.

**Consistency problem:**
If we individually update the address mentioned above on the platform, we need to make sure that the "flat address data" in each (Elasticsearch) document that using this address is also updated... (In this case, the address must be updated for both the person and organisation...)

**Proposed solutions:**
When syncing an object in Elasticsearch that, we include some kind of relationship properties that can be used later on to keep the data consistent, let's say we do it like this:

:Save person with id 1 in Elasticsearch
CURL PUT to URL: http://elasticsearch-server:some_port/testindex/person/1

```
{
    "firstname" : "John",
    "lastname" : "Doe",
    "address" : {
        "street" : "Some street"
        "number" : "1"
        ...
    }
    "relations" : [
        { "entity" : "address", "id" : "1" }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Save organisation with id 1 in Elasticsearch
CURL PUT to URL: http://elasticsearch-server:some_port/testindex/organisation/1

```
{
    "name" : "Some name",
    "address" : {
        "street" : "Some street"
        "number" : "2"
        ...
    }
    "relations" : [
        { "entity" : "address", "id" : "2" }
        ...
    ]
}
```

On the existing platform we would implement this the following logic that would sync an address to Elasticsearch:

1. Save the address-object (For example with id 1)
2. Trigger the synchronisation of this object to Elasticsearch
3. When the sync is done, perform a lookup on Elasticsearch over all types where there is a relation with the entity equals "address" and id 1
4. For each type that is returned, check if this type with the given id exists on the platform and trigger the 'update' and 'synchronisation' of this object. (Since during the sync the address info will be constructed based on the foreign key relation, this will contain the updated info...)

Does anyone have any feedback on this way-of-working? Does the idea work? Anyone had any negative/positive experiences with this way of working?

**Update 1:** Person, organisation and address are only a small selection of the many entities/objects the platform works with... I would like to avoid building any limitations for any future entities/objects...

**Update 2:** Data is synchronised to Elasticsearch because we have an API that can/will be used by third-party companies to retrieve data.

**Update 3:** We are using Elasticsearch 2.0, mappings have to be defined at the design stage, which means of we define (a) parent(s) for a certain document, we would no longer have the flexibility to possibly add other parents in the future. (It's restricted to modify parens for an existing type...)

**PS:** I have already had a look at [parent-child relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) and [nested objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) and due to the limitations they have they do not offer a solution to the problem I have described above.

Comment: re parent/child: If you make the address document a parent document with two children documents (person, organisation documents having the same address), why would that not work?

Comment: @Val: Since we are using Elasticsearch 2.0, mappings have to be defined at the design stage, which means of we define (a) parent(s) for a certain document, we would no longer have the flexibility to possibly add other parents in the future. (It's restricted to modify parens for an existing type...)

Comment: Fair enough, I did not know that info.

Comment: When you update an address, how many docs share that same address? We're talking a few documents, right?

Comment: @Val Correct! However person, organisation and address are only a small selection of the many entities/objects the platform works with... I would like to avoid building any limitations for any future entities/objects...

Comment: Why are you synching the data to ES in the first place? Are you going to enable searching or something? Can you explain a bit more the use case(s) you're after with ES?

Comment: Updated the question with more info at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, though, "retrieve data" is pretty vague, I'm afraid. What I understand is that you'll be using ES only to serve data throughyour API more quickly than what can be achieved with traditional RDBMS, but you won't leverage the search features. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104549/discussion-between-kennyds-and-val).